# Beautifulsoup get text from table grid under located words' grid

Tags: python, html, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup

I wanted to extract information from this table to a csv file, but only the number of grade and age without the "grade:" and "age:" part:

```
<table>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Grade:</b></td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
                
        <tr>
            <td><b>Age:</b></td>
            <td>15</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Most of the tutorials I've find only shows how to parse all the tables into a csv file rather than parsing the next line of located words:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open("1.html") as fp:
    soup = bs(fp, 'html.parser')
    tables = soup.find_all('table')   

filename = "input.csv"
csv_writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w'))

for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    data = []
    for th in tr.find_all("th"):
        data.append(th.text)
    if data:
        csv_writer.writerow(data)
        continue

    for td in tr.find_all("td"):
        if td.a:
            data.append(td.a.text.strip())
        else:
            data.append(td.text.strip())
    if data:
        csv_writer.writerow(data)
```

How should I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method to search for a `<td>` following a `<b>`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select("table tr > td > b"):
    print(tag.find_next("td").text)
```